# Funny write SysCall error: Prints chinese characters in .txt

Tags: c, file-io, system-calls, ubuntu-16.04

Under my virtual box Ubuntu image, I was playing around with the open and write system calls in C and got the funniest error I've ever had!

Basically, I'm obtainig a file descriptor from open and write the input which comes from within the write funnction into a .txt file. The user tells the open function where to look for the file/ where to create the file.

- If the file hasn't been created yet, open will create it for me
- If it is there already, I'll append the input to the end of the file

  ```
  int main(int argc, char* argv[]{
  int fd; 
  int bytesWritten;

  //open and create file if it's not been created yet
  fd = open(argv[1], O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_APPEND , S_IRWXU);
  if(fd == -1){
      perror("Open error:\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  bytesWritten = write(fd,"Hello mate!\n",20);
  if(bytesWritten == -1){
      perror("Write error:\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  //fysnc
  return 0;}
  ```

If I print the output to stdout (1) (change fd to 1), I'll get the expected result:

> Hello mate!

**BUT,** if I use write as shown above things get really weird (and funny)
[image: Error]

It made me laugh, the file gets created and if I execute the programm a couple of times the file will begin to grow and grow.

BTW, I execute the program like this:

> ./copy /home/b/Desktop/Examples/U3/test.txt

I have to admit that this is a pretty funny side effect but why is this happening and how can I solve this?

Just curious

Comment: Maybe gedit guesses the file encoding incorrectly. I would suggest that you use some hex editor to check what content your file really has, to verify that it is OK.

Comment: Or try the output of the cat command in tue Terminal

Comment: @mame98 thx, I forgot to thing about it myself. It prints out an error message which I can't print because of the chinese characters I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright you guys, I just found the solution to this and I have to apologize for wasting your time...

My partner renamed the folder in which the file was (like for ex. from Ü3 to U3) and hit enter. This kind of destroyed the files encoding...

Creating the source file in another, fresh folder resolves the issue..

Comment: I didn't get you have you just created new folder or directory ??

Comment: ***Re***creating the file probably solved the issue.

Comment: Renaming a folder is not expected to touch the content of the file(s) inside the folder, nor would this change the way the file(s) would get interpreted, at least not by `gedit`.

Comment: I solved this by creating a new folder and a new file. This is what caused the error: First, the file has been built. Second,  the folder has been renamed. Third, I executed the *.o file which was created due to the build. This made the file inconsistent  in some way. @alk this is the first time this is happening to me, I've done it before but it never was a issue.

Seems like if you rename your folders and try to rebuild/rerun your source file and Ubuntu can't find it anymore, things like this happen.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
write(fd,"Hello mate!\n",20);
```

more is written than provided.

The string literal has a size of 12+1 `char`s. The code writes 20. So seven come from invalid memory containing garbage.

Doing so invokes undefined behaviour, anything can happen from that moment on.

To fix this you could do:

```
write(fd, "Hello mate!\n", 12);
```

or

```
write(fd, "Hello mate!\n", sizeof "Hello mate!\n" - 1);
```

or

```
#define MYMSG "Hello mate!\n"

...

write(fd, MYMSG, sizeof MYMSG - 1);
```

or

```
char mymsg[] = "Hello mate!\n";

...

write(fd, mymsg, sizeof mymsg - 1);
```

or

```
char mymsg[] = "Hello mate!\n";

...

write(fd, mymsg, strlen(mymsg));
```

or

```
const char * pmymsg = "Hello mate!\n";

...

write(fd, pmymsg, strlen(pmymsg));
```

...

Comment: Great answer, thx for that. But I've  already done it before and there is no issue with printing out more than you actually have. Anyways I implemented your solution but it didn't change a thing , unfortunately.

I played around with open and write before but never had this kind of error.

Comment: `const * char pmymsg = "Hello mate!\n";` Did you mean `char const *`?

Comment: @BigDude: Did you started retesting with a *fresh* (empty) file to write to?

Comment: "*I've already done it before and there is no issue with printing out more than you actually have*" the ugly thing about ***Undefinded** Behaviour* is that it might simply look as if it worked, and the results change unexpected a a later point in time, when you changed something seemingly unrelated. Do not run code provoking undefined behaviour!

Comment: @user694733: Sure, I did. Fixed. Thanks.